# as.POSIX not converting seconds correctly in R

Tags: r, excel, time, posix

I have time series data that is recorded in Excel in their serial data/time format as shown below

```
> t3.b1 <- read.csv("t3_b1.csv", header = TRUE)
> t3.b1$time
[1] 0.73958 0.73970 0.73981 0.73993 0.74005 0.74016 0.74028 0.74039 0.74051
[10] 0.74062 0.74074 0.74086 0.74097 0.74109 0.74120 0.74132 0.74144 0.74155
[19] 0.74167 0.74178 0.74190 0.74201 0.74213 0.74225 0.74236 0.74248 0.74259
[28] 0.74271 0.74282 0.74294 0.74306 0.74317 0.74329 0.74340 0.74352 0.74363
```

I also have a date associated (August 287th, 2017), but I split the data because really all that is relevant are the times. 
I want to convert these in to readable times so that I can use ggplot, which requires them to be in a POSIX format. When I try to convert to readable times, though, I just get the same time over and over:

```
> t3.time.POSIX <- as.POSIXct(t3.b1$time, tz = "AKDT", origin = "1900/01/01 00:00:00" )
> t3.time.POSIX
[1] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[3] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[5] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[7] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[9] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[11] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[13] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[15] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[17] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[19] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[21] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[23] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[25] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
[27] "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT" "1900-01-01 00:00:01 GMT"
```

My times SHOULD be ten second intervals, all occurring on August 27th, 2017. I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have gotten the date format and times to show correctly...almost. These should be just 10 seconds intervals, but some are off by one second. I think this is an issue of converting from a fractional day in Excel to a time. Is there a way to fix this? I.e. make sure that they are showing the correct seconds?

```
> conv.t3.time <- convertToDateTime(t3.b1$date.time)
> conv.t3.time
[1] "2017-08-27 17:44:59 AKDT" "2017-08-27 17:45:10 AKDT" "2017-08-27 
17:45:19 AKDT" "2017-08-27 17:45:29 AKDT" "2017-08-27 17:45:40 AKDT" "2017- 
08-27 17:45:49 AKDT"
[7] "2017-08-27 17:46:00 AKDT" "2017-08-27 17:46:09 AKDT" "2017-08-27 
17:46:20 AKDT" "2017-08-27 17:46:29 AKDT" "2017-08-27 17:46:39 AKDT" "2017- 
08-27 17:46:50 AKDT"...
```

Also, I think this would still need to be converted to POSIX, which doesn't seem to work still...

Comment: It's difficult to see how those numbers can be Excel serial datetime for a date of 2017-08-27; they are too small.

Comment: Ok - so do I need to convert to numeric before trying to convert to date.time?

Comment: In reply to neilfws - I split the date and time data because I thought that might help me somehow, and I only really need the time data. This is what it looks like originally: [1] 42974.74 42974.74 42974.74... etc The decimals were always getting cut off, so I thought that had something to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

Transferring times from Excel to R is always a bit of a nightmare, when you can end up with partial seconds etc. Try this as a bit of a fudge to get it to exactly record to the second:

```
x <- c(42974.73958, 42974.7397, 42974.73981, 42974.73993, 
       42974.74005, 42974.74016, 42974.74028, 42974.74039)

xd <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(x, origin="1899-12-30"))

xd2 <- round(as.numeric(xd))
attributes(xd2) <- c(attributes(xd), tzone="UTC")

#[1] "2017-08-27 17:45:00 UTC" "2017-08-27 17:45:10 UTC"
#[3] "2017-08-27 17:45:20 UTC" "2017-08-27 17:45:30 UTC"
#[5] "2017-08-27 17:45:40 UTC" "2017-08-27 17:45:50 UTC"
#[7] "2017-08-27 17:46:00 UTC" "2017-08-27 17:46:10 UTC"
```